# Как сделать так, чтобы главная картинка статьи отображалась в превью?

Tags: django

Пишу сайт на Django. Нужно, чтобы выводился анонс статей с картинкой. Не знаю как это реализовать.  Использую ckeditor. Картинка не отображается в превью новости,  а видна только тогда, когда заходишь на страницу той или иной статьи.

[image: Картинка не отображается в превью новости, а видна только тогда, когда заходишь на страницу той или иной статьи.]

models.py

```
class News(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
related_name='news_posts', null=True, blank=True)
anons = models.CharField(max_length=350)
body = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
# Возврат понятного отображения заголовка в панель администрирования
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
class Meta:
    verbose_name = u"Новость"
    verbose_name_plural = u"Новости"
```

urls.py

```
  path (r'', views. articles, name = 'news'),#Лента новостей
  path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),#редактор статей
```

vews.py

```
def articles(request):#Страница новостей
    news = News.objects.order_by('-date_added') 
    context = {'new': news}
    return render(request, 'prosvet_logs/news.html', context)
```

Comment: А где у вас картинка хранится?

Comment: я использую ckeditor

Comment: правильно я понял, что у вас картинки лежат в виде ссылок в html?

Comment: Да, вы правы. Редактор статей ckeditor загружает картинку на сервер